# What would be the unit of the vectors spanning the Jacobian matrix?

Tags: kinematics, dimensional-analysis, rotational-kinematics, mathematics

Let the general forward rate kinematics equation be given as follows:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}  \boldsymbol{\omega} \\ \boldsymbol{v} \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}  \boldsymbol{J}_1 & \boldsymbol{J}_2 & \cdots &\boldsymbol{J}_n \\  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_1 \\ \dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_1 \\ \vdots \\ \dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_n \end{bmatrix}$$

The Jacobian, $\boldsymbol{J}_i = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{s}_{i\parallel} \\  (\boldsymbol{s}_{i\parallel} \times \boldsymbol{l}_i)\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{6}$,columns are formed by a direction and moment vectors, i.e., $\boldsymbol{s}_{i\parallel} $ and $(\boldsymbol{s}_{i\parallel} \times \boldsymbol{l}_i)$, respectively. I know $\boldsymbol{s}_{i\parallel}$ is a direction vector which is only dependent on the joint angles and $\boldsymbol{l}_i$ is a position vector to the location of $\boldsymbol{s}_{i\parallel}$. If $\dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_i$ has a unit of $rad/sec$, what would be the unit of $\boldsymbol{s}_{i\parallel} \times \boldsymbol{l}_i$ to get an approperiate dimension for $\boldsymbol{v}$ and $\boldsymbol{\omega}$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You appear confused...  are you *sure* you have not interchanged the positions of ***ω*** and ***v*** ?

Comment: Thank you, Professor. That was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Although it sounds creepy, I would probably get to answer this question on my own.

$\textbf{Answer}$:

Assuming that the direction vector, $\boldsymbol{s}_{i\parallel}$, is dimensionless, multiplying it with the joint velocity ($\dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_i$) having a unit of $rad/s$ yields a quantity with a dimension of $rad/s$. The result has shown consistency with the units of $\boldsymbol{\omega}$. Similarly, the unit of the quantity ($\boldsymbol{s}_{i\parallel} \times \boldsymbol{l}_i$) is $m$. The product of this term with the angular velocity yields a quanity in $m/s$ which is also inline with the unit of $\boldsymbol{v}$.

I hope this helps for others who might have similar questions.

Many thanks for professor Cosmas Zachos [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/66086/cosmas-zachos)

Answer (score 0):

assume you have those equations

$$\underbrace{\vec v}_{\left[\frac ms\right]}=\mathbf J_v\,\underbrace{\vec{\dot{q}}_v}_{\left[\frac 1s\right]}$$

hence the unit of $~\mathbf J_v~$ is $~[m]~$

analog

$$\underbrace{\vec \omega}_{\left[\frac 1s\right]}=\mathbf J_\omega\,\underbrace{\vec{\dot{q}}_\omega}_{\left[\frac 1s\right]}$$

hence the unit of $~\mathbf J_\omega~$ is $~[-]~$

Comment: Thanks. That is right !